# CollapsingToolbarLayout showing broken title when collapsed

Tags: android, kotlin

[Bugged title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51OWz.jpg)

Hey, as you can see in this picture, I am trying to use the CollpasingToolbarLayout but the title is not being drawn correctly. In the expanded state I set the title to fade out like this:

```
val collapsingToolbarLayout = layout.findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(android.R.color.transparent)
```

so the expanded state isn't really important. My xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expanded="false"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <CalendarView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="35dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title="Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/main_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Whan can I try? I am thinking this is a bug but I wouldn't know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` typically adds the appropriate padding in some cases to make sure that views are not layered under the status bar/nav bar. In your case, I think that is the cause of pushing your text downwards.

You may need to play around with this, but try removing it for your AppBarLayout and its children and perhaps try some different combinations.

It may also help to show us the view boundaries so we can see where the views actually are. This can be done either in the Android Studio preview or via developer options